# Why will my Docker containers not talk to each other

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I am attempting to get my node express docker container to talk with my mysqldb container. But when I query I always get: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306'. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my docker-compose.yml. It spins up my two containers. my-api works if I just use express without a container. But not when it is in one. When it is running in docker, express seems to be routing fine, but it will not connect to the database in the other container.

```
services:
  api:
    image: node:8
    container_name: my-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm run start
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    expose:
      - 3000
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
      REACT_APP_BASE_URL: http://localhost:3000
      DB_HOST: localhost
      DB_NAME: test
      DB_USER: test
      DB_PASS: test
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysqldb
    command: mysqld --user=root --verbose
    volumes:
       - ./schemadump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schemadump.sql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "test"
      MYSQL_USER: "test"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "test"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
```

Here is my docker file

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json .

RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Here is my database connection file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

module.exports = function databaseCall (sql) {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME
  })
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqldb` instead of `localhost` -

```
       DB_HOST: mysqldb
```

Containers are accessible by their service name in docker compose environment. `localhost` basically means your API container itself.

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers acts as isolated machines, and they have their own network, including their own localhost.
Docker-compose creates an inner network for you, and you should be able to communicate between your containers using the service name.

For example, from your API, you can reach your database by specifying host as "mysqldb"

Answer (score 0):

Docker container has its own DNS system. Through container name, you are able to access other container but they should be part of one network.

```
// docker compose file 

conatiner_name: api-app
..
 networks:
  - main-network

// other container

container_name:main-app
..
networks:
  - main-network


// In your main app.
await axios.post('http://api-app:3000/entinty-name',{data: { name: "xyz" } });
```